# How to loop through form fields including datagrid checkbox in php and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do i loop form elements and get values and than save to database, i have 5 form input and i have datagrid with checkbox to select row...

so i wanted to know how to perform same using php and codeigniter.,,,, i really need help to solve the problem.

```
 function showattendee($id)
{
    // set validation properties
    $this->_set_rules();

    // prefill form values
    $person = $this->Person_model->get_by_id($id)->row();
    $this->form_data->id = $person->tab_classid;
    $this->form_data->classtitle = $person->tab_classtitle;
    $this->form_data->classdate = $person->tab_classtime;
    $this->form_data->createddate = $person->tab_crtdate;
    $this->form_data->peremail = $person->tab_pemail;
    $this->form_data->duration = $person->tab_classduration;
    $uri_segment = 0;
    $offset = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);
    $users = $this->User_model->get_paged_list($this->limit, $offset)- >result();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('person/index/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->User_model->count_all();
    $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");
    $this->table->set_heading('', 'User Id','User Name', 'Email', 'Language','Actions');
    $i = 0 + $offset;
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
    $checkarray=array('name'=>'chkclsid[]',
            'id'=>'chkclsid','value'=>$user->user_id);

            $this->table->add_row(form_checkbox($checkarray), 
            $user->user_id, $user->user_name, $user->user_email,$user->user_language, 
    anchor('person/view/'.$user->user_id,'view',array('class'=>'view')).' '.
    anchor('person/update/'.$user->user_id,'update',
            array('class'=>'update')).''. 
            anchor('person/showattendee/'.$user- >user_id,
           'Attendee',array('class'=>'attendee')).' '.
    anchor('person/delete/'.$user->user_id,'delete'
            ,array('class'=>'delete',
            'onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to  delete this person?')"))  
        );
    }
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();


    // load view
    // set common properties
    $data['title'] = 'Assign Attendees';
    $data['message'] = '';
    $data['action'] = site_url('person/validatecheckbox');
    $data['value'] = "sssssssssssssssssss";
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('person/index/',
            'Back to list ofClasses',array('class'=>'back'));

    $this->load->view('common/header');
    $this->load->view('adminmenu');
    $this->load->view('addattendee_v', $data);


    }
```

so i wanted to loop all form fields including checkbox value and pass to database to save data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if your are using POST or GET you can just loop the full $post or $get array to determine all of the form values

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>

<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <input type='checkbox' name="cb1" value='a1' />
    <input type='checkbox' name="cb2" value='a2' />
    <input type='checkbox' name="cb3" value='a3' />
    <input type='submit' name='action' value='Check Values' />
</form>
```

I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: i did same but i am getting value of checkbox as Array

Comment: but i am dynamically generating checkbox from database to grid, so any one how check the checkbox i just need to get values of input fields and checkbox